# How does Mathematica compute PseudoInverse?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, implementation-details

What is the algorithm that is used in computing the `PseudoInverse` in *Mathematica*?

Comment: it says in help, that for `numerical matrix PseudoInverse is based on SingularValueDecomposition`. which is known algorithm. And in there it says `SingularValueDecomposition uses the QR algorithm with Givens rotations. PseudoInverse, NullSpace, and MatrixRank are based on SingularValueDecomposition. For sparse arrays, Arnoldi methods are used`. You can look at `tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation#30506` but If you need to know more, apply for a job at Wolfram, then you can look at the actual source code :)